# Составление предложений с "обратными" действиями

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как корректно сформулировать предложение с "обратными действиями"? Допустимо ли написание  таких предложений нормами делового русского языка?
Пример предложения:
С помощью данного оборудования выполняется погрузка (разгрузка) автомобилей на (с) борт(а) эвакуатора.

Answer (score 1):

"С помощью данного оборудования выполняется погрузка/разгрузка автомобилей на/с борт(-а) эвакуатора".

В деловом или научном тексте можно использовать косую черту. Она выполняет роль "или", "одно или другое".

Если не нравится косая черта, можно так:

"С помощью данного оборудования выполняется погрузка и разгрузка автомобилей на борт и с борта эвакуатора".

Answer (score 0):

Предложение не может иметь вид образца бланка типа «Нужное подчеркнуть». Вариант может быть такой: «С помощью данного оборудования выполняется погрузка автомобилей на эвакуатор или их разгрузка».